# Why is this basic menu list off-centre and not aligned with the text below it?

Tags: html, css, layout, centering

Despite having made my own functional website, I'm dreadful with code.

I have bigger issues, but I thought I'd ask this first as it's basic. What's wrong with the code to make the menu list off-centre here?:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GHPE6DVTVV5Q

Comment: Please add the code to the question, preferably in a runnable snippet

Comment: But it's not off-center, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. The result is horizontal scroll-able and your menu items are centered. Try changing orientation on TryIt Editer, at the `top-left` menu icon list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a default CSS interfering here:

```
user agent stylesheet ul {
  padding-inline-start: 40px;
}
```

You need to change:

```
ul#MenuBarFooter {
  padding: 10px 0px;
}
```

Here I let to you the snippet with my change.

```css
#footer_container {
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  width: 980px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  clear: both;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  float: none;
}
    
.footer_nav {
  display: inline;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family:"Trebuchet MS","sans-serif";
}

ul#MenuBarFooter {
  width: auto;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}
    
ul#MenuBarFooter li {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
}
    
ul#MenuBarFooter a {

  text-decoration:none;
  text-align:center;
  color: #0066FF;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 10pt;
}


ul#MenuBarFooter a:hover, ul.MenuBarHorizontal a:focus {
  color: #3333CC;
}
    
.footer_centering {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:10pt;
  font-family:"Trebuchet MS","sans-serif";
  color:#0066FF;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>footer test</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="footer_container">

    <div class="footer_nav">
      <ul id="MenuBarFooter">
        <li class="MenuBarFooter">
          <a href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/index.htm">Pub Maps</a>
        </li>

        <li class="MenuBarFooter">
          <a href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/art.htm">Public   Projects</a>
        </li>

        <li class="MenuBarFooter">
          <a href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/contact.htm">Contact</a>
        </li>

        <li class="MenuBarFooter">
          <a href="http://www.albanydesign.co.uk/index2.htm">Hidden Index</a>
        </li>


        <li class="MenuBarFooter">
          <a href="../abandoned_projects.htm">Abandoned Projects</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <p class="footer_centering">© Steven Lovell / Albany Design</p>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would rather update padding-top: 10px;  padding-bottom: 10px;  padding-left: 0px; to just padding :10px 0px;

Comment: @Brian That's better, I changed my answer with that suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There are default styles applied to all HTML tags in the browser. So the ul tag has got a default padding on the left. If you change your CSS to this it will work

```
ul#MenuBarFooter {
width: auto;
list-style: none;
padding: 10px 0px;}  /*10px top bottom 0px left right */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add this to  `#footer_container{width:100%; max-width:980px }
```

`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it